# Create a JDialog that will automatically close on JProgressBar completion

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, jprogressbar

I am trying to make a JDialog which has JProgressBar in it and it disposes automatically when the Progress bar's progress is completed.

I have tried taking in account Jprogress bar getvalue() function . But it doesnot seem to help

```
public static void createProgressDialog(){
    progressDialog.setUndecorated(true);
    progressBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
    progressBar.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
    progressBar.setStringPainted(true);

    if(progressBar.getMaximum() == 100)

    progressDialog.add(progressBar);

    progressDialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    progressDialog.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.MODELESS);
    progressDialog.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,25));
    progressDialog.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,25));
    progressDialog.setLocation(1600,260);
    progressDialog.getRootPane().setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.gray));

    ComponentMover cm = new ComponentMover();
    cm.registerComponent(progressDialog);

    int progressvalue = progressBar.getValue();
    if(progressvalue ==0)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
    else if(progressvalue ==100)
    {
        progressDialog.dispose();
    }

    progressDialog.pack();        
    progressDialog.setVisible(true);       
}
```

How can i achieve a Dialog which disposes off on JProgressBar's Completion?

Comment: Add a `ChangeListener` to the JProgressBar, or maybe better, to whatever *it* is listening to, and then close the dialog there when the desired state has been reached. The bottom line is that the dialog must be closed in response to an event, not on creation as you're trying to do. What good is checking for progress completion right when you make the JProgressBar?

Comment: I will post an update once its fixed.

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Progress Bars](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html). The example shows how to use a SwingWorker for the background task. When the task is finished the `done()` method is invoked and you would change the logic to close the dialog.